# Optimize C# code for finding non-existing objects on List<T>

Tags: c#

I am making a module that will output a list of objects that are missing on a list. Currently the code I have takes too long for a list of about 300,000 objects.

```
public List<SimpleObject> GetNonExistentObjects()
{
     List<SimpleObject> source = GetNodes();//contains 300,000
     List<SimpleObject> target = GetNodes();//contains 300,005

     List<SimpleObject> nonExistentObjects = new List<SimpleObject>();

     foreach(Object obj in source)
     {
          bool existing = target.Any(x => x.Name == obj.Name && x.Label == obj.Label)
          if(!existing)
               nonExistentObjects.Add(obj);//Contains 5 objects
     }

     return nonExistentObjects;
}
```

I have to create a bunch of methods like this so I would like to ask how to optimize this particular method.

UPDATE:
`T` is just a simple class that I have created that contains 2 properties. Just that

```
public class SimpleObject
{
     public string Name {get; set}
     public string Label {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: do you mean target.any?

Comment: @Ewan edited the code, yes I mean target.Any

Comment: Something wrong with the existing `Except` method on `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @Oded: using `Except` naively would just compare the equality of node references, I guess.

Comment: @DocBrown added the edits

Comment: Does the SimpleObject have value semantics?

Comment: @Telastyn no, `SimpleObject` is really just a class with 2 string properties

Comment: Then why does your "exists" check focus on the value if your object should have reference semantics?

Comment: @Telastyn I stand corrected. I made the object unique based on those 2 properties. So that's why "exists" compares based on the values of those 2

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636438/difference-between-two-lists#5636486

Comment: GetNodes() returns different results in 2 calls?   Source is the smaller but it has 5 items not in Target?

Comment: @Paparazzi I have configuration values changed before calling the second `GetNodes()` method. So the 2 `GetNodes` methods are getting result from different data sources. I ommitted them in this code to simplify

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` for your class `SimpleObject` (and implement them correctly). Then you can use the `Except` method of LINQ, like suggested by @Oded in [a comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331151#comment705378_331151):

```
nonExistentObjects = source.Except(target).ToList();
```

[`Except` uses a `HashSet<T>` internally](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e289e6c98881b2b8), which makes it very fast.

Here is an example how to implement the two methods I mentioned above:

```
public class SimpleObject
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Label { get; set; }

     public override bool Equals(object obj)
     {
         if (obj is SimpleObject)
         {
              var so = (SimpleObject)obj;
              return so.Name == Name && so.Label == Label;
         }
         return false;
     }

     public override int GetHashCode()
     {
         return Name.GetHashCode() ^ Label.GetHashCode();
     }
}
```

Comment: nice solution!!

Comment: although shouldn't it be target.Except(source)?

Comment: Don't forget to enclose GetHashCode code in an unchecked { } section, in order to suppress overflow-checking for integral-type exponentiation. It'll work fine, and it'll save you a lot of trouble debugging strange errors. Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx

Comment: @Machado: ^ is not exponentiation in C#, it is the XOR operation, so no overflow can occur here. But for other hashing function, you are right, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404715/c-sharp-hashcode-for-array-of-ints/3404820#3404820).

Comment: @Ewan: not the way the OP posted his question, his code puts elements from `source` into `nonExistentObjects`.

Comment: @DocBrown, you're absolutely correct. My mistake. Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: There's also an overload with `IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer` if you don't want to alter your `SimpleObject` class.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a suboptimal use of collections to me. Can you use HashSet instead of List for target collection? Remember, in that case, you would have to redefine GetHashCode and Equals methods of classes that would be put in those collections.

Answer (score 2):

Put the searched values into a IDictionary

so something like :

```
indexedTarget = target.ToDictionary(i=> i.Name + "_separator_" + i.Label)

indexedTarget.ContainsKey(obj.Uid  + "_separator_" + obj.Label);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx

as doc comments, string concatenation for the key isnt great. there must be a way to do the full test in one line of code without it.

```
indexedTarget = target.ToDictionary(i=> i.Name)

MyClass dupe;

if(IndexedTarget.TryGet(obj.Uid, out dupe) && dupe.Label != obj.Label) { nonExistentObjects.Add(dupe);}
```

edit : note on equality comparer solutions.

Personally I hate adding the extra GetHashCode and Equals Methods to poco classes. Its a good solution when you are always comparing things and there is a firm definition of what makes two of them equal. But it can get onerous when the definition is not as clear. ie this time you want to match the name AND label, but next time you just want to match the name

Comment: I recommend removing your last comment. The dictionary is the way to go, it's O(N). Building the two sorted lists is O(N*log(N)) and will take more time to build as N increases.

Comment: you are right!!

Comment: Maybe I am biased, but "magic separator" solutions for creating dictionary keys look always like an ugly hack to me. I have written such code in the past by myself, but today I typically avoid it. Those solutions are short, of course, but you have to be sure the separator is never part of the input data, and you need to make sure the magic string is the same whereever you create keys for the same dictionary.

Comment: I agree, but I didn't want to complicate the example

Comment: Dictionaries throw an exception if the key is not found, so your line `var dupe = indexedTarget[obj.Uid]` will not work as expected. Instead use `indexedTarget.ContainsKey`.

Comment: I thought that had been changed. But i see im getting it ci fused with adding values

Answer (score -1):

I would use the Overide and Equal of Doc Brown +1

```
public IEnumerable<SimpleObject> GetNonExistentObjects()
{
     List<SimpleObject>    source = GetNodes(); //contains 300,000
     // List.Add is O(1)
     HashSet<SimpleObject> target = GetNodes(); //contains 300,005 

     foreach(SimpleObject s in source)
     {
          if(!target.Contains(s))   // O(1)  LINQ ANY is O(N)
               yield s; //Contains 5 objects
     }
}
```